# Как отправить запрос в форму на сайте и получить ее?

Tags: android

В общем алгоритм задачи такой.
1. Класс активити создает объект в виде строки
2. Эта строка должна попасть в форму на сайте и сделать post запрос на получение данных
3. После должно произойти парсинг полученной информации с рамки ответа
4. И результат должен вернутся в активность

Сам вопрос:
1. По первому пункту вопросов нет
2. Какую библиотеку подключить для записи в форму html строки и осуществления post запроса при помощи submit
3. Парсинг результата через jsoup библиотеку лучше сделать??

Я начинающий поэтому с api андроид не знаком и вообще не знаю как правильно это сделать с точки зрения архитектуры

Comment: Плохая практика обращаться к сайту через html, по хорошему нужно работать с сервером который просто принимает post запрос и возвращает json.

Comment: проблема в том, что к серверу не имеется доступ.

Comment: Сервер сторонний ресурс предоставляющий услугу